# creating a new dataframe from an old one by selecting only some values from a list

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am a newbie with both Python and [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), and I have this question:

I have this dataframe: [text](https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/gdp/gdp_csv/data/0048bc8f6228d0393d41cac4b663b90f/gdp_csv.csv)
It's data about countries and their GDPs for different years. There are 256 countries, but I want a dataframe with only just a few countries, 10 or 12 countries.

So, to give a simple example, let's say I only want 4 countries, I managed to create a new dataframe, `df2`, like that:

```py
df2 = df[(df['Country Name'] == 'European Union') | (df['Country Name'] == 'United Kingdom') | (df['Country Name'] == 'Spain') | (df['Country Name'] == 'United States')]
```

It seems a very slow way to create `df2`, especially if I want more countries in my new dataframe. Is there a way to use a list of countries, and use that list to create `df2`?

I tried:

```py
countries = ['European Union','United Kingdom','United States','Spain']
df2 = df[df['Country Name'] == countries]
```

But I get the error:

> ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (11507,), (4,))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can do it like this:

```
countries=['European Union','United Kingdom','United States','Spain']
df2 = df[df['Country Name'].isin(countries)]
```